# Calculating the shortest path between any two vertices u,v in G

Tags: python, igraph

I want to find the set S that contains *the shortest path* between any two vertices in a graph.
The following code is working fine, but I am not sure if there is a more efficient code that does the same functionality.

```
def getShortestPaths(g):
    shortestPaths = []
    #iterate all pair of nodes 
    for x in itertools.combinations(g.vs["label"], 2):
        path = len(g.get_shortest_paths(v=x[0],to=x[1])[0]) - 1
        shortestPaths.append(path)
    return shortestPaths
```

Comment: Floyd-Warshall is the thing to do.  Something that should make it obvious why a speed up is possible: If you find the shortest path between two nodes `a` and `b`, and it goes through `c`, then you must have also found the shortest `a` to `c` path and `c` to `b` path.  So there will be no need to calculate those paths.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The efficiency of your current code depends on the implementation of `g.get_shortest_paths`. Typically choices of `g.get_shortest_paths` include:

- [Bellman–Ford algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bellman%E2%80%93Ford_algorithm), which shall run at `O(VE)`,
- [Dijkstra's algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dijkstra%27s_algorithm), which shall run at `O(V^2)` without optimization, `O(Elog(v))` or even `O(E+Vlog(E/V)log(V))` if well-optimized.

And the time cost of your code shall be the cost of `g.get_shortest_paths` times `O(V^2)` since the iteration.

For all-pairs-shortest-path problem in your case, [Floyd–Warshall algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Floyd%E2%80%93Warshall_algorithm) is suggested which uses dynamic programming to reach a time cost of `O(V^3)`

**EDITED:**

Notations used above: `E` for number of edges, and `V` for number of vertices in the graph.

Comment: Uh, I see, I was late. +1 mine will meet Ockham's razor =).

Answer (score 2):

I implemented the unoptimized [Dijkstra's algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dijkstra%27s_algorithm) for a given graph in python some time ago:

```
def define_undirected_G(): 
   m = 10 #nodes
   G = [set() for _ in range(m)]  #create a set for each node 
                                  #and save the adjacent nodes inside these sets 
   G[0] |= {1,2}
   G[1] |= {0,2,3,4}
   G[2] |= {0,1,4,6,7}
   G[3] |= {1,4}
   G[4] |= {1,2,3,5}
   G[5] |= {4}
return G
```

---

```
def dijkstra(G,s): 
       m = len(G) 
       d = [None]*m  #Shortest paths from s to all nodes in G
       d[s] = 0      #Path cost=0 for the startnode
       Q = {u for u in range(m)}   #Q = All nodes u in G
       while Q: # Selection of node with min d-value
           (_,v) = min({(d[u],u) for u in Q if d[u]!= None})
           Q.remove(v) 
           for u in G[v]: #Check Update for all adjacent nodes
               alt = d[v] + G[v][u]   #Greedy-selection-rule            
               if d[u]==None or alt < d[u]:   #Update
                   d[u] = alt 
       return d
```

If you want to have a set S containing all shotest paths from all nodes in G, then just calculate dijkstra(G,s) for s in G and add the result to S.

Note: Optimization will be ***Union Find Data structure*** and the change of ***for u in G[v]*** because there is no need for checking adjacent nodes which were already updated and removed from untouched set of nodes Q because greedy algrotihms are greedy.

Hope this helps.