# Dijkstra's algorithm on adjacency matrix in python

Tags: python, algorithm

How can I use Dijkstra's algorithm on an adjacency matrix with no costs for edges in Python? It has 1 if there is an edge between 2 vertices and 0 otherwise. The explanations that I've found on the internet are all for graphs with costs.

Comment: Just assume all edges have cost 1.

Comment: See [Calcuating the shortest path between any two vertices u,v in G][1].


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29512280/calcuating-the-shortest-path-between-any-two-vertices-u-v-in-g/29514527#29514527

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Dijkstra's algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dijkstra%27s_algorithm) requires edge cost to work. If you want to run the algorithm on a graph with "no costs", I'll assume that you're trying to find the *shortest* path between 2 vertices in terms of *number of edges* in the path.

In that case, you can just assume that every edge has cost 1, and Dijkstra's algorithm will work as intended. Make also sure that you ignore non-existing edges in your search (you don't want the zeroes in the matrix to be counted as zero-cost edges).

Answer (score 2):

If you have no weights, you could either use Dijkstra and define `weight = 1` for all edges or use a [BFS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Breadth-first_search), which is basically a special case of Dijkstra but without weighted edges.

Answer (score 0):

When I had to implement Dijkstra's algorithm in php to find the shorter way between 2 tables of a database, I constructed the matrix with 3 values : 0 if the 2 points are the same, 1 if they are linked by an edge, -1 otherwise.

After that the algorithm just worked as intended.